# How to store Data from a scanner to Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase, Firestore project that scans a QR Code and uploads the scanned data to Firebase Firestore. I want to store a history of the previously scanned QR COdes in Firestore but whenever I scan a new QR Code, the data gets replaced by the recently scanned QR Code. I think the data keeps getting replaced because the field name **(ScannedItem)** in my case, does not change, instead it updates the value.

How do store the data in a way that it makes a new field each time a new QR Code is scanned.

I am a newbie, please help.

Code of the scan method and the Firebase Firestore storage

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor_ns/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns.dart';

import 'package:barcode_scan_fix/barcode_scan.dart';

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:user_details/DrawerPages/AboutInfo.dart';
import 'package:user_details/DrawerPages/Cards.dart';
import 'package:user_details/DrawerPages/Profile.dart';
import 'package:user_details/DrawerPages/Transactions.dart';
import 'package:user_details/fromJP/Payment_page.dart';

import 'button_widget.dart';

class Scan_QR extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Scan_QRState createState() => _Scan_QRState();
}

class _Scan_QRState extends State<Scan_QR> {
  String qrCode = "";

  String Username = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName;
  String Email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.amber);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Scan QR Code"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("lib/bg.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ButtonWidget(
                              text: "Press to Scan QR Code",
                              onClicked: () async {
                                scanqr1();
                              },
                            ),
                          ])),
                ]))));
  }

  Future scanqr1() async {
    final qrCode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    setState(() {
      this.qrCode = qrCode.toString();
    });

    if (qrCode.isNotEmpty) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => _buildPopupDialog(context));
    }
  }

  Widget _buildPopupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        scrollable: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        title: Text(
          "You Scanned the Following Product:",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontSize: 23),
        ),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              qrCode,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: scanqr1,
            child: Text(
              "Re-Scan",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Map<String, dynamic> scaneditem = {
                "ScannedItem": qrCode.toString(),
                "Created On": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
              };
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("product")
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                  .set(scaneditem);
              print(scaneditem);

              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Payment_page()));
            },
            child: Text("upload",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amber)),
          )
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are setting the data on one document or in other words you are overwriting the data. You have to add a new doc on each data to store the previous history

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("product")
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
              .collection("scannedItems")
              .add(scaneditem);
```

This will add a random doc id and it will be like this

```
product
  -> uid(doc)
   -> scannedItems (col)
    -> unique doc id (doc)
     -> ur scanned data (doc data)
```

Then you can retrieve it by QuerySnapshot. I hope it is clear now

**OR**
You can store userId along the scanned items, so you can direct query the doc
First, add the user id in the data itself

```
Map<String, dynamic> scaneditem = {
            "ScannedItem": qrCode.toString(),
            "Created On": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            "user_id":id,
          };
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("product")
              .add(scaneditem);
```

Now you have

```
product
    -> unique doc id (doc)
     -> ur scanned data (doc data along with userid)
```

You can get it like

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("product").where("user_id",isEqualTo:"id").get();
```

Comment: This Really helped me, I now want to put the scanned data in a List

Comment: You can use streambuilder->Listview.builder->Text(scannedData).
Let me know if you need help in coding

Comment: Yes, I need help in coding.

Comment: Yes what query you want to return?

Comment: I want to return all the scanned items in the form of a history list.

Comment: I was able to do all that but when I get the list it only displays for a second then forever displays a ```CircularProgressIndicator()```

Answer (score 0):

firestore is a nosql db , you need to create new documents for each scan
.
 `.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)` means it will use this id at all times for the doc. you can let firebase generate ids and save user id per scan document

```
Map<String, dynamic> scaneditem = {
                "ScannedItem": qrCode.toString(),
                "Created On": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                "uid":FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid.toString()
              };
               DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("product")
                  .doc()
                  .add(scaneditem);
              print(scaneditem);

//to get doc id you just uploaded 
 String docId = documentReference.documentID;
```

//you can update your document to add the id

```
Firestore.instance
                  .collection("product")
                  .document(docId)
                  .updateData({ ..yyour data })...
```

Comment: the ```.add(scaneditem)``` throws an error that says its not part of the ```DocumentReference```. it only alows set(), which alslo throws an error